# Multiple objects in php without using loops or recursion?

Tags: php

I want to know that, In PHP is it possible to create n objects of a class
without using loop or recursion.

Like we can use array in c++.

Something like this

```
class sample { /*** code goes here ******/ }
 sample[100];
```

Comment: There are any number of ways how you can dress up a loop without using the `for` keyword specifically, but in the end you'll always have a loop of some kind or another. This is not a very productive question, as in practice a loop is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in a way, you can:

```
$a   = array();
$a[] = new sample();
$a[] = new sample();
...
```

But what is it that you're trying to accomplish?

If you need to create an array of N objects in a concise way, you can add a static factory method allowing you to get N objects into an array, and *that* method would internally use a loop:

```
$a = sample::array(20);
```

...which is more or less what C++ and other languages do; the [N] syntax does not work magically by itself.

The construct *may* then be unrolled by the compiler for (small) constant values of N and you would get the equivalent of the above `$a[]=new; $a[]=new; ...` code.

You can have a no-loop object creation if there is no actual initialization whatsoever, in which case array[100] is just a way of reserving memory. You could have some kind of a "lazy" arrayable object (uninitialized entries are just taking up a little memory, and are initialized on access when needed), but not in PHP as far as I know. And you would just be slipping the loop under the rug by offloading it to the code:

```
$a = new sample[20];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++) {
    if (...) { // Some elements might be kept "semi-uninitialized"
        // do something with this object
    }
}
```

## Traits

With a recent PHP, you can even add this "arrayability" as a Trait:

```
<?php
Trait Bunch
{
    public static function bunch($number) {
        $bunch = [ ];
        while ($number--) {
            $bunch[] = new self();
        }
        return $bunch;
    }
}
```

Now in any other class you can declare that it uses `Bunch`, and this will allow you to get a *bunch* of instances:

```
class Test
{
    use Bunch;

    // Common counter, static among all instances
    private static $counter = 0;

    // Dynamic counter for each instance
    private $instance;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->instance = ++self::$counter;
        $this->identify();
    }

    public function identify() {
        print "I am number {$this->instance}\n";
    }
}
```

And finally:

```
// Get a bunch of 20 instances of Test.
$lots = Test::bunch(20);

// Request the sixth instance to identify itself again.
$lots[5]->identify();
```

The above code will count from 1 to 20. Note that since arrays are counted starting from 0, $lots[5] will therefore identify itself as number #6.

The advantage is that in any class you just add

```
use Bunch;
```

and the `bunch()` function becomes available. This isn't so useful for a simple trait like this, but you may find it useful for more complicated designs.

Comment: I am trying to print 1 to 100 without using any loop and recursion. 
To accomplish this i created a class and incrementing a global variable in its constructor and printing there.

Now i just want to create its 100 objects which will print 1 to 100 counting.

Comment: @user If that's your only goal: `echo join(' ', range(1, 100));`

Comment: It works,
Thats really great. Thanks.

But i will like to know whether is there way to achieve the goal using classes? (Asking just for better understanding)

Comment: I think you can do this with traits. Not sure. Tried to add something to the answer.